# What's a free flash IDE that supports netbeans/eclipse style shortcuts?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, ide, shortcut

I tried flashdevelop and the basic flash cs5 IDE, and both fail miserably in the shortcuts department.

I am very comfortable with the netbeans set of shortcuts and want to know if there's any AS3 IDEs that would support them.

Some examples are:

```
ctrl+/ for toggle comment
control+shift+up/down to duplicate a line
alt+shift+up/down to move a line up and down
ctrl+D to delete a line
alt+shift+f to autoformat
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain that you can change the shortcuts for FlashDevelop. I don't think you'll find an editor that's better, either..

Comment: Not without spending a truckload of money. FlashDevelop is the way to go. You can always jump in and contribute to add what you need. It is open source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page) is the best. Quick, intelligent and powerful. Love it.

You have total control over such customizations. And honestly... if you find you *actually* can't make certain changes (in this case - hotkey shortcuts), accommodating the application's minor differences  is a small price to pay for such an elegant programming environment, imho.

Comment: Problem is, shortcuts are restricted by the .xml format. For instance you can't seem to use "/" in a shortcut. Escaping it with \ doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

All of these are easy to edit in the xml.

```
Ctrl+Q to toggle a comment
ctrl+shift+D to delete a line. 
not sure about the auto format.
```

you could add a line to your MainMenu.xml for the line duplication:

```
<button label="Duplicate Line" click="ScintillaCommand" tag="LineDuplicate" shortcut="Control|Shift|Up" flags="Enable:IsEditable" />
```

for the adding a line etc. and all the other commands you have access to they have it posted here. http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=3729

FlashDevelop is the best tool as everyone has said. Most of us swear by it.

Comment: How would I go about setting control+/ ?

Comment: I am not sure. Because of the xml structure I am not sure you can. I would ask on the flashdevelop forums. That would be your best bet for an answer.